# Using React to display List of Cruise Ships by Cruise Line

Tags: reactjs, web

At the moment I am doing a website on cruise ships using React.

I have got so far with it, but now I am stumped on how I can show List of Ships based on the specific Cruise Lines.

Note: that this is on the Cruise Lines Page.

Here is a link to my repository (https://github.com/RobertWSON/Personal-ship-project/tree/practice-animation-react-slick) and the up to date code is on `practice-animation-react-slick` branch

I have used map function in `listofShips.jsx` component

[This website example](http://www.cruiseshipodyssey.com/worlds-fleet/) I found doesn't use react, but shows ships based on specific cruise.
I also want to have my list expand and collapse for the specific cruise lines and I might use Accordian to do this.

The code below is what I have in my `ListofShips` component, but this is only good for displaying all cruise ships, which I don't want.

```
import React from 'react'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'
import {getAllShips} from '../api/api'

class ListofShips extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
      super(props)

      this.state = {
        shipList: []  
      }
      this.setUpShips = this.setUpShips.bind(this)
    }

    componentDidMount(){
      console.log('cdm')
      this.setUpShips()
    }

    setUpShips() {
      console.log('getallships')
      getAllShips()  
      .then(res =>{

        this.setState({
          shipList: res  

        })
      })
    }

    buildShipName(ship) {
      return ship.cruise_line ? (ship.cruise_line + ': ' + ship.ship_name) : ship.ship_name
    }

 render()  {
    return  (

     <React.Fragment>

           {this.state.shipList.map(ship => {

           return  <li className="shipsList" key={ship.cruise_line + '-' + ship.ship_name}><Link to={`/ship/${ship.id}`} >{this.buildShipName(ship)}</Link></li>

})}

       </React.Fragment>
      // </div>
    )
  } 


  }


export default ListofShips
```

My expected result is to have lists of ships for specific cruise lines.
I would also like to have expanding and collapsing lists for each cruise line.

Comment: What does `getAllShips()` promise return? And have you tried logging `this.state` in the component's `render()` method?

Comment: have lists of ships for which specific cruise lines? where do you get that value? and where do you filter `shipList` object based on that value?

Comment: I am using dev.sqlite3 database and I have all cruise lines and ships details kept in ships.js seeds file, under seeds folder.
With this I also have migrations and an api file in client folder. Currently if you view it on localhost 3000 you can see that I have list of all ships, but that is not what I want.

I have not filtered ShipList yet for ships based on cruise line. 
To do this, I am wondering how I can alter my my ListofShips.js file (including map function), along with files like api.js and db.js. Hopefully I don't have to adjust to much to make  this work.  Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @user3210641
getAllShips () promise returns all ships and it is also in api.js. 
You have made me think. should I really have getSomeShips(), as I want some ships based on cruise line. Do you mean this.state console log inside render().

I am using dev.sqlite3 database and all details are kept in ships.js seeds file. I also have migrations and an api file in client folder. Currently if you view it on localhost 3000 you can see that I would rather have ships by cruise lines. How I can alter (map) in ListofShips.js file , along with api.js and db.js, to make this work. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: I managed to get Cruise Line Headings showing on my Cruise Lines page. Now, when I click on Cruise Line Heading to get a List of Ships it is not working and it comes up with an error that says ListofShips is not defined. The question I need to ask you now is, is this happening because I have getListofShips in my backend and ListofShips for my Component, so is it clashing? Would it be better to call it getShipsList in the backend, so it works. I'd appreciate your feedback on this, as we're here on this post to help each other out with their web development problems

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter the result to a specific cruise line, the easiest solution would be [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method.

```js
// Copied from seeds/ships.js
const ships = [
  {
    id: 1,
    cruise_line: "Royal Caribbean",
    ship_name: "Symphony of the Seas",
    img: "/images/Symphone-of-the-Seas-heading-left-OU2.jpg",
    Year: 2018,
    Gross_Tonnage: 228081,
    Passenger_Full_Capacity: 6680,
    Double_Occupancy_Passenger_Capacity: 5518,
    Length: 362.1,
    Beam: 47.448,
    Draft: 9.322,
    Height: 72.5,
    Loaded_Displacement: 120000,
    Deadweight: 18095,
    Review: '' 
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    cruise_line: "Fred Olsen",
    ship_name: "Boudicca",
    img: "/imagwes/Boudicca_at_Funchal_2016_(bigger).jpg",
    Year: 1973,
    Gross_Tonnage: 28372,
    Passenger_Full_Capacity: 900,
    Double_Occupancy_Passenger_Capacity: 880,
    Length: 206.96,
    Beam: 25.22,
    Draft: 7.55,
    Height: 45,
    Loaded_Displacement: 21156,
    Deadweight: 5956,
    Review: '' 
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    cruise_line: "Fred Olsen",
    ship_name: "Black Watch",
    img: '',
    Year: 1972,
    Gross_Tonnage: 28613,
    Passenger_Full_Capacity: 868,
    Double_Occupancy_Passenger_Capacity: 804,
    Length: 205.47,
    Beam: 25.20,
    Draft: 7.55,
    Height: 45,
    Loaded_Displacement: 20704,
    Deadweight: 5656,
    Review: ''       
  },
];

// "Royal Caribbean" only
const shipsOne = ships.filter(ship => ship.cruise_line === 'Royal Caribbean');

// "Fred Olsed" only
const shipsTwo = ships.filter(ship => ship.cruise_line === 'Fred Olsen');

console.log(shipsOne); // Ship with ID 1
console.log(shipsTwo); // Ships with ID 5, 6
```

If you want to group the ships by cruise lines, your best bet is [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method.

```js
// Copied from seeds/ships.js
const ships = [
  {
    id: 1,
    cruise_line: "Royal Caribbean",
    ship_name: "Symphony of the Seas",
    img: "/images/Symphone-of-the-Seas-heading-left-OU2.jpg",
    Year: 2018,
    Gross_Tonnage: 228081,
    Passenger_Full_Capacity: 6680,
    Double_Occupancy_Passenger_Capacity: 5518,
    Length: 362.1,
    Beam: 47.448,
    Draft: 9.322,
    Height: 72.5,
    Loaded_Displacement: 120000,
    Deadweight: 18095,
    Review: '' 
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    cruise_line: "Fred Olsen",
    ship_name: "Boudicca",
    img: "/imagwes/Boudicca_at_Funchal_2016_(bigger).jpg",
    Year: 1973,
    Gross_Tonnage: 28372,
    Passenger_Full_Capacity: 900,
    Double_Occupancy_Passenger_Capacity: 880,
    Length: 206.96,
    Beam: 25.22,
    Draft: 7.55,
    Height: 45,
    Loaded_Displacement: 21156,
    Deadweight: 5956,
    Review: '' 
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    cruise_line: "Fred Olsen",
    ship_name: "Black Watch",
    img: '',
    Year: 1972,
    Gross_Tonnage: 28613,
    Passenger_Full_Capacity: 868,
    Double_Occupancy_Passenger_Capacity: 804,
    Length: 205.47,
    Beam: 25.20,
    Draft: 7.55,
    Height: 45,
    Loaded_Displacement: 20704,
    Deadweight: 5656,
    Review: ''       
  },
];

const groupedShips = ships.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  const currentCruiseLine = cur.cruise_line;
  
  if (acc[currentCruiseLine]) {
    return {
      ...acc,
      [currentCruiseLine]: [...acc[currentCruiseLine], cur],
    };
  }
  
  return {
    ...acc,
    [currentCruiseLine]: [cur],
  };
}, {});

console.log(groupedShips);
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the reply with filter and reduce code. 
I would like to have that sort of code in separate file from seeds, ships.js. 
In seeds, ships.js, I only would like id information for ships and cruise line within export seeds. To make this work, could I combine filter and reduce with map in ListofShips.jsx component. Also I'm thinking in api.js could I have getSomeShips instead of getAllShips and getShip (id) may have to change. Under server, db.js and ships.js, I think will have to change. Are you able to give me further advice, as to how I can make this work?

Comment: Have you seen my comment in response to your code.
Can you please reply to me on what I have said in response.
I am just quite stuck at the moment on moving forward with this and I have just got to get a good understanding on how I can make this work.